# Zip a video file in Phonegap before upload

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I am using the Phonegap capture video method to capture and upload videos, however I want to zip the file before uploading to server.

Is there any means of compressing a file on client-side?

How efficient is this?

And any pointers would be appreciated.

Ismael

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to be able to transfer videos faster to my server so if I have a very large video recording, say 20MB I need this to be uploaded to a server this'll take quite some time however if I am able to compress somewhat hoping the reduction in size makes it possible to transfer faster.

Comment: and you measured the size gain ? i am quite surprised that lossless compression can achieve anything on a video.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native API to do this. However, You can try this library called JSZip:

http://stuartk.com/jszip/

Answer (score 0):

I would condider converting the file to mpeg compression instead.

try this jquery libary [link](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php)

then you don't need to unzip the file, you can just play it as a compressed format.